# Pyramid - fanstatic application cannot find static resources under apache wsgi module

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid, fanstatic

I have a Pyramid-Fanstatic application that I created using pcreate:

```
pcreate -s starter -s pyramid_fanstatic
```

All works ok if I use /bin/pserve-fanstatic to start the server. However when I use the Apache WSGI module to load the app, a link like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fanstatic/services/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

returns 404 Not Found by Apache.

This is my WSGI application:

```
import os
activate_this = os.path.join('/opt/services/services/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/opt/services/python-eggs'


from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/opt/services/services/development.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

This is my Apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin a.orth@cgiar.org
    ServerName data.ilri.org

    # Pass authorization info on (needed for rest api).
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    WSGIDaemonProcess services python-path=/opt/services/services display-name=services processes=2 threads=15
    WSGIScriptAlias /services /opt/services/services/services/services.wsgi process-group=services application-group=%{GLOBAL}

    <Location /services>
                WSGIProcessGroup services
    </Location>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/services.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/services.custom.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I can see that /bin/pserve-fanstatic includes my resource directory before loading the application:

```
"""A script aware of static resource"""
    import pyramid.scripts.pserve
    import pyramid_fanstatic
    import os

    dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    dirname = os.path.join(dirname, 'resources')
    pyramid.scripts.pserve.add_file_callback(
                pyramid_fanstatic.file_callback(dirname))
    pyramid.scripts.pserve.main()
```

But even if I include such lines in my init.py Apache cannot find the fanstatic resources.

I also added this to my ini file:

```
[filter:fanstatic]
use = egg:fanstatic#fanstatic

[pipeline:main]
pipeline = fanstatic services
```

What else should I check/do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!!

I had to add this lines to the ini file in [app:main]:

```
fanstatic.publisher_signature = fanstatic
fanstatic.use_application_uri = true
```

as per the documentation at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_fanstatic

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be telling Apache to serve up your static files. See:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting_Of_Static_Files

Comment: Yes, I read through it, tried some things but at the end was some configuration in the ini file as I indicated in my answer.